# Assigning void* to UINT or unsigned int

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, visual-c++-2010, visual-c++-2012

I learned this today at my work place. And I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344505/pointers-size-with-respect-to-ram-architecture), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109666/size-of-pointers-dependent-factors) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241205/are-all-data-pointers-of-the-same-size-in-one-platform?lq=1) before posting my question.

Here's what my senior co-worker told me:

> You cannot assign void* to UINT or unsigned int. It won’t work for 64 bit.

But why? Is it because `void*` and `unsigned int` carry different sizes on different architectures (as mentioned in other questions), or something else?

Comment: Did you try `printf("%u\n", sizeof(void*));` with each of your compilers included as tags?

Comment: Related: http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0005/ In short, yes, there's a difference on _most_ systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the target for your application. You tagged `VC++` and mention type `UINT` - thus it seems that you're building for Windows. In 32-bit Windows the pointer size is 32 bit, while in 64-bit Windows it's 64 bit. However, size of type `UINT` is defined similarly to 32 bit for both Windows flavors. You can use `__uint64` or `UINT64` MS-specific type instead of UINT to ensure it's big enough for your pointer. You can also use `INT_PTR`/`UINT_PTR` types which are specifically designed to match the size of the pointer (thus making it transparent for 32/64-bit flavors).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx for reference on various data types.

Of course, all of these will make your program not natively portable to other architecture/OSes.

Answer (score 2):

You're essentially correct:  **It is not guaranteed that an `unsigned int` has the same machine word length as a `void*`**, so you can't cast between them without losing information.  [Here](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/generic.html) is an excellent FAQ answer about it.

The main thing to keep in mind is that `void*` is an arbitrary *data pointer*, not a truly arbitrary pointer.  In fact, there is no such thing as a truly generic pointer:  certain machines may have different address spaces for programs and data, for example, so the sizes of pointers to each might differ.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6908720/1830736) for more info.

Comment: While it's correct that void* isn't a generic data pointer, the question is about size of void* compared to size of integer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the case.

Your implementation may provide the optional type `uintptr_t`, however, which is defined as follows:

> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid
>   pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> `uintptr_t`

The signed counterpart `intptr_t` may also be available. These types are available in the `<cstdint>` header.

By choosing to use these types, you are acknowledging that your code will only compile with the subset of implementations that provide this types on your target machines.

Answer (score 2):

Size is obviously a show-stopper, if `void*` can't physically fit in an `unisigned int` the game is over.  But even if `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(unsigned int)` you have a type compatibility problem: one holds a data pointer, the other data.  You'd have to `reinterpret_cast<>()` the one to the other and all bets are off as to how well this would work.